# Swift core data does not store data permanently

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have an Entity called "Friend".. Attributes are name and age..here I have implemented bridging because NSManagedObject class for Friend has .h and .m file.  My code to store data:

```
var err: NSError?
var delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var friend:Friend = Friend(entity: NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Friend", inManagedObjectContext: delegate.managedObjectContext), insertIntoManagedObjectContext: delegate.managedObjectContext)
friend.friendName = "Mani"
friend.friendAge = "23"
delegate.managedObjectContext.save(&err)
```

My code to retrieve data

```
var result: Array = delegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend"), error: &err)
println("reslut \(result)")
```

So when I retrieve, it gives result with data..but its not stored permanently..if I quit and run the app then previous data has gone..can anyone tell me what is the issue with my code...

Here is the sample project https://github.com/rnystrom/Swift-CoreData  I got it from Github..this project also has same issue..

Comment: Baaad Design: var delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate Anyway, have you checked the return value of the save method, and if it returns false, printed the error (like so: println("\(err)") ? It might give you a clue.

Comment: i just printed the error..its nil..can you please suggest how to write good design if my code is bad desgn?

Comment: Is the error nil AND the return value false? Because if the save method returns true, it actually did save, and there is no error. If the method returns false and there is no error, most likely the managedObjectContext is nil. For the appDelegate issue, start reading this: http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/

Comment: thanks for the tutorial..yes..there is no error..but not saved permanantly..do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

What is the return value of the save method, is it true or false? Can you show what the output is of the following line, if you place this right before the line with the save method:

```
println("delegate: \(delegate); MOC: \(delegate.managedObjectContext)")
```

Comment: delegate: <_TtC12SampleThur0311AppDelegate: 0xb234be0>; MOC: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xb6134d0>
saved successfully

Comment: Looks good. Can you also print out the array and error you get from executing  the fetchrequest?

Comment: i am really sorry ..now only i understood...data stored correctly

Comment: So what was the problem, or what did you mont understand, that you do understand now? Please share, so others finding this question can learn.