# Swift core data does not store the data permanently

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode6

I also have the same problem with ([This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545845/swift-core-data-does-not-store-data-permanently)) but he doesn't tell the solution. Therefore, I have to ask you how I can do ?
I have an Entity called Rabbits, Attributes are birth_date,breed_date,cage_no,dam_earnum,nes_date,pal_date,rabbit_id,sire_earnum

My core data store :

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rabbits")
        var result:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
        request.includesSubentities = false
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var rabbits = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Rabbits", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
        rabbits.setValue(buckTextField.text, forKey: "sire_earnum")
        rabbits.setValue(doeTextField.text, forKey: "dam_earnum")
        rabbits.setValue(cageTextField.text, forKey: "cage_no")
        rabbits.setValue(breedDate, forKey: "breed_date")
        rabbits.setValue(palDate, forKey: "pal_date")
        rabbits.setValue(nesDate, forKey: "nes_date")
        rabbits.setValue(birthDate, forKey: "birth_date")
        rabbits.setValue(index, forKey: "rabbit_id")
        context.save(nil)
```

My code to retrieve data :

```
var result: Array = delegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rabbits"), error: &err)
println("reslut \(result)")
```

So when I retrieve, it gives result with data..but its not stored permanently..if I quit and run the app then previous data has gone..can anyone tell me what is the issue with my code...

There are some suggestion of Joride that tell me to show the out put of the return value of save method that true or false with this following code :

```
println("delegate: \(delegate); MOC: \(delegate.managedObjectContext)")
```

I got the message : `delegate: <BreedRabbit.AppDelegate: 0x7f8ad9d03b20>; MOC: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7f8ad9c300b0>`

How I can do next ?

Comment: Are you definitely calling `save` on your `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Yes, I do this way and it can permanently store before Xcode have the lasted update. Do you think it affect ?

Comment: Why are you saving entity as "Rabbits" and retrieving "Friend" entity? are you sure code provided above is correct?

Comment: I put wrong code. My code is all "Rabbits"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching wrong entity with your fetchrequest. Try change this:

```
var result: Array = delegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend"), error: &err)
```

to this:

```
var result: Array = delegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Rabbits"), error: &err)
```

Comment: I did it but the still gone.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible reasons for data not being actually saved are:

- Using NSInMemoryStoreType when creating your persistent store coordinator;
- Having entity properties set to Transient in the model editor.

Please, check that to rule out these possible causes.

Comment: Thank you guys. How i can check it ? Can you explain please ?
I add my core data following this instructor : [http://craig24.com/2014/12/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-swift-project-in-xcode/]

Comment: I suppose you've created the Core Data stack in AppDelegate; if so, open AppDelegate and find a statement saying circa `psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error:&error)`. If you have NSInMemoryStoreType instead of NSSQLiteStoreType, that's your problem; if you have NSSQLiteStoreType, you should then check that `modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataModelName", withExtension: "momd")!` has exactly the name of your .xcdatamodeld file (but don't touch "momd" as extension).

Comment: To check that you don't have Transient properties in your data model (point 2 of my answer) you should clic on the yourdatamodel.xcdatamodeld file, clic on your entity and, for every attribute, clic on it in the list and check that in the Utilities panel on the right of your screen, third section ("Show the data model inspector") Transient is unchecked.

Comment: I have check in point one and point two that you tell me and there are correct at all.