# When I close the application I got Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How can I solve this problem, I don't know that did it affect to my problem in this link [My previous problem about Core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012086/swift-core-data-does-not-store-the-data-permanently) ?

This message will occur when I cmd+Q of the application.

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

and if who know the solution of my previous problem please tell me.

Comment: I guess this is some kind of timing problem. SIGTERM is sent from the debugger to your app in order to terminate it. Usually this is caught and the app will terminate. But sometimes it got hit "on the wrong foot" and you see the message. On a real device this will not occur since you do not kill your app.

Comment: When you say "cmd+Q of the application," what do you mean? There is no "cmd" key on iOS to quit an application. Are you quitting the simulator? Are you quitting Xcode?

Comment: So, no problem with this message right ? Thank you so much Thomas Kilian.
Sorry Rob Napier, I mean on simulator and I got the message from Xcode console.

Answer (score 20):

- `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15` occurs whenever the user manually terminates the application (whether simulated in iOS simulator or on a provisioned iOS device) through CMD-Q (Quit) or `STOP`, which is toggled after you click on `RUN`.
- In OS terms, signal 15 is a Linux enumeration for the signal, `SIGTERM`, which means signal terminate.

Answer (score 3):

Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15 usually means that you quit the simulator while running the program.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue when i take screen short from simulator then terminated. This is xcode bug.

Just update your xcode version.

Comment: then how you solved it ? i am also facing the same problem . so how did you manage to take the screen shot of the simulator ?

Comment: I did not get any solution but if you are using xcode version 8.2.1 then just update your xcode, this is xcode bug.

Comment: yes , it seems like this is some kinda xcode bug . and yes everything is updated but still i am getting this error though.

Comment: no . i am using 8.2 , and there is no update notification regarding xcode on app store . is version 8.3 is out on air ? how to get it ?

Comment: First you need to your mac OS version 10.12 then after you get xcode update notification. xcode 8.3.1 must required OS version 10.12.

Comment: yes that i have figured it out regarding os update . thanks for the heads up . i hope that will solve the simulator issue .

Comment: rofl. if you update xcode, run your app, then stop it, you will find this bug is following you.

Answer (score 0):

> This only means that the system sent your application the kill signal. The system may do that for any number of reasons. It does not necessarily mean the application was killed due to memory pressure. In fact, this is very unlikely in the case that you describe. Most of the reasons the system might send a kill signal won't happen when the app is being debugged.
>
> When the system kills an application it will track the reason and log it. If you are using a third party crash reporting service this will not capture the reason, and in fact can prevent a lot of critical information from being logged by the system.
>
> Look for logs on the device. Watch the console log on the device when the issues reproduces - usually you will be able to see why it was killed. If it was memory pressure there would be a JetsamEvent log as well.
>
> It is much more likely that your application is doing something "in the background" that it does not have a background mode or entitlement for. For example, it may be doing something past the background task assertion time limit, etc.
>
> As far as your CPU and memory use, do not trust the gauges in Xcode. These are just an estimate and are often way off, and they do not capture the information you actually need (like dirty VM usage). Instead use Instruments.

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/822id9/ideas_for_debugging_a_memory_leak_terminated_due/