# Swift passing array between swift files for tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a button action in one viewcontroller connect to another tableviewcontroller. I need to pass a few textfields value to show in another tableview via click the button. In the first view, I have a global array:

```
var estRent = [AnyObject]()
```

Append value within the buttonAction:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   ...
   estRent.append(weekRent)
   estRent.append(monthRent)
   estRent.append(yearRent)
   estRent.append(interestRate)
   estRent.append(loanAmount)
   estRent.append(monthInterest)
}
```

Overwrite prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! NextTableViewController
        svc.rentArray = self.estRent
    }
}
```

In the NextTableViewController, there is a global array:

```
var rentArray = [AnyObject]()
```

The next table view could not see the values in the array. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean could not see the values?

Comment: I mean when I click the button, the table view could not see anything. So I guess the array hasn't been passed. But I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: add breakpoint on the statement `let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! NextTableViewController` and update me your result whether was that statement executed.

Comment: When are you trying to access the array? Because your `NextTableViewController` will be created before the `rentArray` property is set. So if you try to access the array in an initialization method, nothing will be there.

Comment: I want to access the array when I fill in the textfield and click the button. How can I realize this?

Comment: I add the break point, it showes "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15".

Comment: why are you terminating the simulator?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31196493/5637872

Comment: The line var rentArray = [AnyObject]() initializes a blank Array of type AnyObjects. By the time the NextTableViewController is setup, thr rentArray is a fresh array. Try making it an Optional and just unwrap it before using it.

Comment: The button action is the trigger, I have overwritten the prepareForSegue, how to make the secondTableView get the array when I finish the button action?

Answer (score 0):

### First View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var classTextField: UITextField!

    var estRent = [AnyObject]()

    @IBAction func goButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        estRent.append(nameTextField.text!)
        estRent.append(ageTextField.text!)
        estRent.append(classTextField.text!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        [estRent .removeAll()]
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        print(estRent)
        if (segue.identifier == "LoadView") {
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! RentTableViewController
            svc.rentArray = self.estRent
        }
    }

}
```

### RentTableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class RentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var rentArray = [AnyObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return rentArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "studentCell")
        let tableCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let rentLabel: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 25))
        rentLabel.text = rentArray[indexPath.row] as? String

        tableCell.addSubview(rentLabel)
        return tableCell


    }

}
```

[Click here for Main.storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKoo.png)

You must give a segue identifier as "LoadView" in storyboard

[Click here to view screen short for "How to give segue identifier"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyQ1r.png)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I add prepareForSegue function in both of the viewcontrollers and already solved it. Cheers.

Comment: I created a sample project. Use the following Git hub link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/SampleTableView